Can't approve deployment via CLI/REST API even when there are pending deploys
I have a case in which, for a given environment, some repos can be set to auto-deploy while other repos require manual approval. I landed on a pattern of using another parallel job to auto-approve it when appropriate.
jobs:
  job-before-staging:
    # Whatever the job before the approval-maybe-required job is.
    # We just need this to anchor the next two jobs to run in parallel.

  # this env has deploy protection rules on it, must be manually approved
  deploy-staging:
    needs: job-before-staging
    env: STAGING
    if: runStaging == true
    # ... deploy steps here


  # no env declared here
  staging-auto-approval:
    needs: job-before-staging
    if: runStaging == true && requireStagingApproval == false

    steps:
      - name: auto-approve-deploy
        run: <the API to approve the job>

Using the API, whether through gh api or curl, I can get the env id, the job id, and the pending_approvals of the current job. I can not get the approval to work.
This code works, to get pending deploys:
gh api --verbose repos/$REPO/actions/runs/$RUNID/pending_deployments

This returns JSON data, proving it can see the pending deploy.
This code to try to approve the pending deploy fails:
gh api --verbose                                      \
  repos/$REPO/actions/runs/$RUNID/pending_deployments \
  --method POST                                       \
  -F "environment_ids[]=$ENVID"                       \
  -f "state=approved"                                 \
  -f "comment=Auto-Approved by GitHub Actions"      

Result:
{
  "comment": "Auto-Approved by GitHub Actions",
  "environment_ids": [
    11130481765
  ],
  "state": "approved"
}

...

{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": "No pending deployment requests to approve or reject",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/actions/workflow-runs#review-pending-deployments-for-a-workflow-run",
  "status": "422"
}

* Request took 469.770458ms
gh: No pending deployment requests to approve or reject (Validation Failed)

I'm also using this perm block, with no effect:
    env:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}

    permissions:
      checks: write
      deployments: write
      actions: write

Update after more testing
I was getting the feeling that the token perms were the underlying cause here. I stumbled on this
action: https://github.com/activescott/automate-environment-deployment-approval which talks about the github.token not being able to be set to the correct perms, and a PAT must be used.
I created a PAT with the appropriate perms of just repo, and it still does not work with the CLI.
However, I then tried using the 3rd-party action to do the approval, and it works with the PAT, and not with the github.token, as expected.
It would take a lot to reverse-engineer activescott's code to understand if I'm doing something wrong in my code. But, I've proven that it's possible to do this, and the PAT works in the much-more-robust 3rd-party action's code, just not in mine.
So the question is if there's something wrong in my code, or something missing from GitHub's API backend that is making my code not work (naturally I assume the former).
One more thing to try is to create a fine-grained token; maybe since GitHub is trying to move away from PATs, it will work differently. :crossed-fingers:

I figured this out. The trick is that you can't use the github.token in the request. You have to create a PAT with repo perms, and pass that in as env.GH_TOKEN.
Also, make sure you're supplying the correct environment_id; I wasted a lot of time with the wrong ID in my local testing script.
